# How do I execute a function after another function is complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought this would be quite simple, but for some reason I can't translate other suggestions to my particular problem.

I've got the following code:

```
function flipText(){
    $(".intro").flipping_text({
        tickerTime: 15, 
        customRandomChar: false, 
        tickerCount: 10, 
        opacityEffect: true, 
        resetOnChange: false 
    });
    }
          
flipText();
```

Now after my function `flipText` is done running, I want to run a simple `alert` that alerts that the function has completed.

So something like

```
fliptext().complete(function(){
    alert("code completed");
});
```

Only then in proper JQuery.

I came across a post that suggested adding a callback, but I can't seem to figure out how to translate that to my specific situation.

Comment: Is the flipping_text method from a plugin? If so, that method may have a callback. In that case, you would pass your callback function into flipText and register it with the flipping_text method's callback.

Comment: It's from the plugin `flipping_tex` by Pete R. Unfortunately, there is no callback mentioned anywhere in the documentation or on github.
https://github.com/peachananr/flipping_text

Comment: You can write simple if else condition if(function completes){alert('complete');else{return false;}

Comment: Having looked at the documentation and source code for the plugin, I think you may be out of luck. Doesn't appear to be any support for a callback function and it doesn't use any Deferreds that you could use either. You'd probably need to go in and change the source code.

Comment: @vamsi `if(function completes)` That does not sound like proper jquery/javascript?

Comment: @user3008011 - you're right, it's not. Ignore that comment.

Comment: Should be easy enough to have a callback at the end of the plugin's main `for...loop`...

Comment: OP probably meant "after flipping_text() is done running", not "after flipText() is done running", otherwise the solution is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as others have indicated in the comments, the support for a callback must be implemented in the plugin itself.

I was able to fork the existing flipping_text project and create a fix that allows for a callback. The project is [here](https://github.com/gordolio/flipping_text). You'll need to check out the new code.

```
$(".intro").flipping_text({
  tickerTime: 15, 
  customRandomChar: false, 
  tickerCount: 10, 
  opacityEffect: true, 
  resetOnChange: false,
  callback:function(){
    alert('all Complete');
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bSUsL/)

Comment: Are you serious? You actually went trough the trouble of re-writing a plugin to provide a callback for my specific problem? You sir.. are awesome!